# How do I get try and catch to work in my code?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, webdriver, browser-automation

Goal: When calling on 'initializeDriver', I don't want to have to keep throwing an IOexception in another class.

How do I properly implement a "try" and "catch" to my code? here is my attempt, however, it's not working correctly. I have tried looking around but I may not be understanding it correctly.

Here is a link to my gitHub in case anyone wants to take a look: https://github.com/intuitive86/Sample_Driver_Test

```
package resources;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Base {

  public WebDriver driver;
  protected Properties dataProperties;

  public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {
    // Create global property file
    dataProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream dataPropertiesInputStream = null;
    try{
      InputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
      dataProperties.load(dataPropertiesInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String browserName = dataProperties.getProperty("browser");
    System.out.println(browserName);

    if (browserName.equals("chrome")) {
      WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browserName.equals("firefox")) {
      WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me. As I understood, you need to hide the IOException which shows from another area.

```
try{
  InputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
  dataProperties.load(dataPropertiesInputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Remove `e.printStackTrace();` from catch block and provide some logger.

```
try{
  InputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data.properties");
  dataProperties.load(dataPropertiesInputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
  logger.error("I got IO exception, no need to worry, it's normal", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. You understood correctly. Anytime I go into another class and use `extends` to my "Base" class, I want to call on WebDriver initializeDriver and not have to keep adding `throws IOexception` as my Base class is setup up to consider that everytime I use it.